Microsoft graph api get the total count of sites in one hit
The graph api doesnt support adding $count to the the search API, neither does it allow querying sites with count.
Is there any way to get the total number of sites in a system with one hit.
Variations tried:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*&$select=name&$top=999
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?$count=true
Thanks

I would try the endpoint which can be used to enumerate all sites in a non-multi-geo tenant.
/v1.0/sites/getAllSites?$count=true

/v1.0/sites/getAllSites?$count=true&$top=999

The response will contain @odata.count property
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites",
    "@odata.count": 600,
    "value": [
    ...
    ]
}

Be aware that this endpoint supports only application permissions. It doesn't work with delegated permissions.
